# Gitolite3 not writing

Tags: httpd, log-files, git, gitolite

I am a bit at world's end here. I want to install gitolite3 smart http over apache. I can successfully pull, but not push (doesn't even give me any errors or notices, not even in any known log). I have disabled selinux until I figure out whats wrong. My OS is CentOS6.4. I'm pasting all my relevant confs and logs, but they all seem fine..

**What is(are) the next step(s) for me to look at?**

Can someone tell me if their gitolite3 log entries for pushed calls are different than mine below?

Process:

```
$ git clone http://flo@server/git/testing
$ cd testing/
$ echo "This is a test" > testing.txt
$ git add testing.txt 
$ git status
$ git commit -am "Added test file"
$ git status
$ git push http://flo@server/git/testing
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf testing
$ git clone http://flo@server/git/testing
$ ll testing
total 0
```

/etc/httpd/logs/access_log

```
10.42.43.1 - - [07/Aug/2013:11:43:09 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 481 "-" "git/1.7.1"
10.42.43.1 - uncleflo [07/Aug/2013:11:43:09 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "-" "git/1.7.1"
10.42.43.1 - - [07/Aug/2013:11:44:01 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 481 "-" "git/1.7.1"
10.42.43.1 - uncleflo [07/Aug/2013:11:44:01 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 151 "-" "git/1.7.1"
10.42.43.1 - - [07/Aug/2013:11:54:54 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 481 "-" "git/1.7.1"
10.42.43.1 - uncleflo [07/Aug/2013:11:54:54 +0100] "GET /git/testing/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "-" "git/1.7.1"
```

/etc/httpd/logs/suexec.log

```
[2013-08-07 11:43:09]: uid: (650/gitolite3) gid: (650/gitolite3) cmd: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
[2013-08-07 11:44:01]: uid: (650/gitolite3) gid: (650/gitolite3) cmd: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
[2013-08-07 11:54:54]: uid: (650/gitolite3) gid: (650/gitolite3) cmd: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
```

/var/lib/gitolite3/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-2013-08.log

```
2013-08-07.11:43:09 6104        access(testing, uncleflo, R, 'any'),-> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:43:09 6104        trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,testing,uncleflo,R,any,refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:43:09 6104    pre_git testing uncleflo    R   any -> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:43:09 6104        system,git,http-backend
2013-08-07.11:43:09 6104    END
2013-08-07.11:44:01 6122        access(testing, uncleflo, W, 'any'),-> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:44:01 6122        trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,testing,uncleflo,W,any,refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:44:01 6122    pre_git testing uncleflo    W   any -> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:44:01 6122        system,git,http-backend
2013-08-07.11:44:01 6122    END
2013-08-07.11:54:55 6226        access(testing, uncleflo, R, 'any'),-> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:54:55 6226        trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,testing,uncleflo,R,any,refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:54:55 6226    pre_git testing uncleflo    R   any -> refs/.*
2013-08-07.11:54:55 6226        system,git,http-backend
2013-08-07.11:54:55 6226    END
```

For the testing repo: gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf

```
repo testing
    RW+     =   @all
    RW+     =   daemon
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitolite3.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerName        git.example.com
#    ServerAlias       git
#    ServerAdmin       you@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/git
    <Directory /var/www/git>
        Options       None
        AllowOverride none
        Order         allow,deny
        Allow         from all
    </Directory>

    SuexecUserGroup gitolite3 gitolite3
    ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/
    ScriptAlias /gitmob/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/

    <Location /git>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Git Access"
        Require valid-user
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/git.passwd
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Suexec wrapper for gitolite-shell
#

export GIT_PROJECT_ROOT="/var/lib/gitolite3/repositories"
export GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME="/var/lib/gitolite3"

exec /usr/share/gitolite3/gitolite-shell
```

Comment: Is it an empty repository? Did you commit within a branch? what `git branch -avvv` return?

Comment: '$ git branch -avvv' returns nothing, empty. Yes, testing is an empty repository, and I am committing from master..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an empty repo, you must first create a branch before committing:

```
git checkout -b master         # creates the master branch
echo ...                       # creates the test file
git commit -am "first commit"  # commit in the right branch
git push -u origin master      # actually push something
```

The next push will only need a `git push`.

See "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)" for more on that initial step.

If you don't create a branch, you are committing in a **[detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)**, which is never pushed (hence the lack of visible changes on the remote -- gitolite -- side)

Comment: ...so in short: There was no error. @VonC, you're a master! I was looking at a working installation!

Answer (score 0):

I also got some problem while setting smart http with gitolite. After successfully done I wrote a how to in my blog [post](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/06/01/how-to-install-own-git-server-with-ssh-and-http-access-by-using-gitolite-and-gitweb-in-centos/).